# How do you say "a meme" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some words combined with an image can go viral and really stay in your head. This is a pretty universal concept. So how does one say it in the international language?

[image: strigo cxu]

How do you say "a meme" in Esperanto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Esperanto version of Wiktionary](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vortaro_angla-Esperanta_m), it's *memeo*:

> [**meme**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meme) - memeo

Comment: I avoid using Wikipedia and Wiktionary as a source of translations. Everyone can come up with a bad translation.

Comment: @Vanege: I'm not saying to trust it, just to check it. Also, remember to check Sonja's English-Esperanto Dictionary: http://esperantodictionary.org/about.php

Comment: My own thought is that it would be good courtesy to check any dictionary at all. Also, speaking only for myself, if a person finds himself asking for lots of words that turn out to be in Wells or Benson, then this person should probably consider getting a copy of Wells or Benson. I don't know that there is (or even should be) a policy on this, but it seems like good manners to me.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander I don't think it is right to push someone to buy a book, instead of letting him making questions which answers will be freely available to everyone in the Internet. It is better the help the whole community instead of one individual.

Comment: To underscore, the above was "my own thought." You're welcome to disagree. For my part, good manners dictates that if you can look something up yourself, you should. Good manners also dictates that if someone has gone to a lot of trouble to compile a dictionary (as Wells and Benson have), it is not OK to scan this and put it on the internet for free. This is true whether we're scanning the whole work at once or one word at a time.

Comment: Everyone can come up with a bad translation, but Wikipedia and Wiktionary have a process of checks and balances, as it were: different people work on it and so more often than not some consensus is reached. It might still not be fully objective, but it's intersubjective more than purely subjective. I think they're very good starting points for looking up many things. If you want certainty, you'll want to check other sources as well, but they can at least help you get started and know which search terms to use when looking further.

Answer (score 14):

I mostly see the word "memeo" being used for this on the internet.

Comment: Is memeo pronounced Me-ME-o or MEEM-o?

Comment: The word is pronounced like it is a normal Esperanto word: "me·ME·o".

Comment: I was hoping so, since that's my preferred way in english